# select control validation using ngClass in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am having a little styling issue when using select control in Angular reactive form. Have a look at my code :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" [ngClass]="{ 'has-success': form.controls.field.valid && !form.controls.field.pristine, 'has-danger': !form.controls.field.valid && !form.controls.field.pristine}">
                <label class="form-form-control-label">Field</label>

        <select class="form-control" formControlName="somevalue">
           <option *ngFor="let field of fields" value="{{field.id}}">{{field.name}}</option>
        </select>

        <span class="help-block [style.display]="form.controls.field.valid || form.controls.field.pristine ? 'none': 'inherit'">
           <small *ngIf="form.controls.field.hasError('required')">
               field is required.
           </small>
        </span>

    </div>
 </div>
```

I am using this structure for every input in the form. Upon validation, this code works fine, it does not submit the form if any field is invalid and the borders of the invalid fields get red thanks to [ngClass] I have used in the parent div. But **in this particular field, I have used select control to select from dropdown and in this field the validation error is shown but the red highlight on the borders isn't displayed**. I think there is some default style of select control overriding this. Any one knows why the select control isn't getting red border upon invalid submission like the rest of the input fields? I am using input tag in other fields.

P.S. By default the value of select control is undefined so its invalid only when the user forgets to select an item from the dropdown before submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. I figured out that the select control had a styling of white border with an !important attribute. It was obvious but I didn't know the meaning of !important at the time of asking. Turns out, I just had to remove the !important attribute on the border style and voila ! it's fixed.